# from some(x) to real type in scala

Tags: scala, dictionary, types, functional-programming

When I get element from map of type `Map[Int,Int]`, I get `Some(24)`, and I can't use `+,-,*,/` operations for it, because it is not an `Int`. Could you tell me how can I get `Int` type value from that map instead of `Some(24)`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That is because `Map.get( key )` returns an `Option`.

You can use following safer approaches,

You can use pattern matching for this,

```
val yourIntOption: Option[ Int ] = yourMap.get( "someKey" )

// yourIntOption will be Some( i ) if key found or None if no such key.

yourIntOption match {
  case Some( i ) => println( i + 1 )
  case None => println( "None" )
}
```

Or, you can choose to stay inside the `Option` `monad`,

```
val yourIntOption: Option[ Int ] = yourMap.get( "someKey" )

val intOptionAfterAdding: option[ Int ] = yourIntOption.map( i => i + 1)
```

Also, you can use following unsafe ( can throw exceptions ) approaches

```
val yourInt = yourMap( "someKey" )
// will throw a NoSuchElementException if this key is not found.
```

Or,

```
val yourIntOption: Option[ Int ] = yourMap.get( "someKey" )
val yourInt = yourIntOption.get
// will throw a NoSuchElementException if the option was None.
```

Or, You can use a somewhat Ok-ok approach

```
val yourIntOrDefaultMinusOne = yourMap.getOrElse( "someKey", -1 )
```

Answer (score 1):

`Map` has an `apply` method that will return the value directly.  You can call it like this:

```
val v = map(key)
```

However, be aware that if the key is not in the map it will throw a `NoSuchElementException`.  I advise you to get familiar with the `Option` paradigm.